# Get next item in array using iterator using flags

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iterator, iteration

I am trying to obtain the next object in an object of objects (is you get my drift). I'm looking through the a list of songs, and trying to determine the next song to play. I use the flag `playing` to check if the song is being played, then i get the index of the next song and add the id to a var called `song`

```
    var stop = false;
    var song = null;
    $.each(playlist,function(index, value){
        if( !value.played ){
            if( stop ){
                song = index;
                return false;
            } else {
                if ( value.playing ) {
                    playlist[index].playing = false;
                    stop = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    playlist[song].playing = true;
    playlist[song].played= true;
```

here is what the object looks like:

```
{
 'hash1': {name:'test',played:true,playing:true},
 'hash2': {name:'test2',played:true,playing:true}
}
```

The problem is, my code only ever plays the first two songs in the playlist. Why is this, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

p.s. here the function is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h1m7bx8g/

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue would give us more to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/h1m7bx8g/

Comment: Your logic needs to be worked out a bit more - the variable ```stop``` will always be false in how you defined your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.each(playlist,function(index, value){
        if( !value.played ){
            if( stop ){
                song = index;
                return false;
            } else {
                if ( !value.playing ) {
                    playlist[index].playing = false;
                    stop = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

outputs

```
(index):87 hash2
(index):87 hash3
(index):87 hash4
(index):87 hash5
(index):87 hash1
```